# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in widget magento 1.9.4.0

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing issue of toOptionArray() in widget. I tried all of the way but not fixing this issue.

> widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <modulename_article type="modulename/article" translate="name description" module="modulename">
        <name>Article</name>
        <description type="desc">Article</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter1>
                <label>Brands</label>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>multiselect</type>
<source_model>modulename/system_config_source_brands</source_model>
            </parameter1>
        </parameters>
    </modulename_article>
</widgets>
```

> ModuleName\Model\System\Source\Brands.php

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_System_Config_Source_Brands{

    public function toOptionArray(){
        $options =  array();

        $options[] = array(
            'value' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Only Text'
            );    
    }}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Hello there is a lot of possibility can you show yout config.xml (Model are defined as modulename)?

Answer (score 0):

You declaring your source model as

`modulename/system_config_source_brands`

but your model is missing the config folder.
Please create a folder between system and source so it becomes

`ModuleName\Model\System\Config\Source\Brands.php`

or declare your source model to be

`modulename/system_source_brands`
And modify class name to
`Namespace_ModuleName_Model_System_Source_Brands`